# Cannot display data when calling method from class inheritance PHP

Tags: php

> Hi everyone, I'm a new programmer and I'm programming an event website
> project. I have some issues about fetching data when calling method
> from child class. Could anyone help me?

**Database.php**

```
class Database {

private $dns = "mysql:host=localhost; dbname=event_management; port=3306; charset=utf8mb4";
private $username = "root";
private $password = "";
private $pdo, $stmt;

public function __construct()
{
    try {
        $this->pdo = new PDO($this->dns,$this->username,$this->password);
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (Exception $th) {
        Message::showMess("Connection failed: ".$th->getMessage());
    }
}

public function crudData($query,$param=[], $option=[]){
    try {
        $this->stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query,$option);
        $this->stmt->execute($param);
        return $this->stmt;
    } catch (Exception $th) {
        Message::showMess("Error: ".$th->getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Query.php**

```
include "Database.php";
  class Query extends Database {
  private static $selection;
  private $query;
  private $param = [];

  public function __construct($query){
    $this->query = $query;
  }

  public function execute(){
    return $this->crudData($this->query, $this->param);
  }
}

//Run code
$query = new Query("SELECT * FROM events");
print_r($query->execute());

/* Result ---------------------
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\FinalProject\database\Database.php:22 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\FinalProject\database\Database.php(188): Database->crudData('SELECT * 
FROM e...', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\FinalProject\database\Database.php(194): Query- 
>execute() #2 {main} thrown in`
*/
```

[event_table_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLapx.png)

Comment: Can you please try and instantiate Database class. Before $query = new Query("SELECT * FROM events"); put $database = new Database();

Comment: I have instantiated it on function execute() and it cannot display

Comment: I believe you haven't because you have overriden the constructor. Maybe before - $this->query = $query; put parent::__construct();

Comment: @g9m29 Oh, I have fixed it based on your answer, thanks for a lot.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help :)